# How do I make money in a legal, moral way from home with my computer, without interacting with humans or uploading photo id?

Tags: working-from-home, information-technology, money

I ***do*** have:

- A computer.
- Programming skills (scripting general logic, making WWW requests and interacting with a local database).
- The technical ability to send and receive Bitcoin with my Bitcoin Core wallet.

I ***do not*** have:

- People skills.
- A photo id.
- Any money to speak of.
- Friends, family or associates.

I need to make money for my personal survival.

I cannot do:

- Illegal things.
- Immoral things.
- Things that in any way involve photo ids, interacting with people, running websites, using "social media", etc.

What can I possibly do? Surely there must be some way for me to survive, given the few things I do have?

I don't expect you to reveal your "secret trick" which you've found and which you would never share in detail, but maybe you can at least give me some pointers or ideas for me to explore?

I have literally spent the last 20 years (!) trying to come up with something, while learning and learning and trying all kinds of things. Nothing has ever worked out. It's quite critical for me to get something going now, so I hope that this will be taken seriously.

I'm not looking to "get rich quick". It would rather be "get the ability to survive, extremely slowly", given that I've been trying for two decades by now. I almost cannot believe it myself, so I understand if you think I'm some kind of "lazy bum". Still, I ask you to not respond with sarcasm or jokes. To me, this is very serious and scary.

Is there perhaps some kind of emerging decentralized network where I could thrive? Where I could provide some sort of valuable service and get paid in BTC? I've looked for a very long time for something like that, but sadly only found ghost towns and vaporware.

Comment: the hard part here is the requirement for anonymous payment. You need a bank account of some sort to recieve money. If its just lack of photo Id you could try using an unregistered paypal account or something

Comment: "interacting with people..." If you can't interact in person or face-to-face, would you be open to interacting with people by email, text chat, phone, Web forum, etc.?

Comment: Also, are you able to receive payments through a bank account, Paypal, Venmo, or other payment services? If so, you'll have more options for making money than if you accept Bitcoin only.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can you perform/receive freelance work anonymously?](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/7449/can-you-perform-receive-freelance-work-anonymously)

Comment: Are you a self-aware AI? Is that why no one will give you a photo ID? Are you located in North Korea? Are you trying to avoid creditors? Are you trying to avoid alimony payments? Are you suffering from agoraphobia? There are many viable solutions for all kinds of scenarios, but without knowing exactly why these particular constraints are affecting you, it's almost impossible to suggest something that can work for you in our current society.

Comment: Why would websites not be an option for you? You can develop websites anonymously. You can also create your own portfolio website anonymously, because there are hosting companies that accept Bitcoin.

Answer (score 6):

You can try freelancing as you don't need to engage with anyone directly with this type of work, and a photo ID is also not essential.
Here are some of the tips that may benefit you.

1. You can start freelancing with your skills and can quickly get some work to do.
2. You can start working on freelancing platforms like Fiverr, Upwork, Freelancer, PeoplePerHour, etc. You can earn a sizeable amount of money. But as you mentioned, you can't get paid in BTC on these platforms.
3. Try to polish your skills as much as feasible, and you can surely get clients for the services you will offer.

I hope these points can help you. If you still have any questions, feel free to discuss them.

Answer (score 4):

If you develop mobile or desktop apps... you can sell them online via the Google Play Store, iOS App Store, Mac App Store, etc.

For example, the following [monetization options](https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/earn/monetization-options) are available for Android apps on Google Play:

> ### Monetization options:
>
> - [In-app purchases:](https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/earn/in-app-purchases) Use Google Play Billing to sell items and additional features, or to remove ads. Take advantage of automatic
>     conversion to local prices, with options to round for local pricing
>     patterns or set local prices yourself, pricing templates, promotion
>     codes, and the ability to sell both durable and consumable virtual
>     goods.
> - [Subscriptions:](https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/earn/subscriptions) Use Google Play Billing to offer users ongoing access to content or services for a recurring fee. Use features such
>     as flexible billing frequencies, free trials, introductory and local
>     pricing, payment grace periods, upgrades and downgrades, price
>     changes, conversion analytics, and billing reports and dashboards.
> - [Advertising:](https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/earn/show-ads-admob) Get paid for showing Google AdMob ads, including features such as native ads that allow you to match ads to your app’s
>     look and feel.
> - [Rewarded Products:](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_rewarded_products) Using Google technology and advertiser demand, provide your users with rewarded videos. You use the same
>     integration used for in-app purchases on Google Play and the products
>     are managed in the Play Console.
> - [Paid apps:](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6334373) Set a price for your app that the user must pay before they can download and install it. Here, you can also take
>     advantage of automatic local pricing (or set prices yourself), promo
>     codes, and pricing templates.
> - [E-commerce:](https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/earn/goods-and-services) Use Google Pay to sell physical goods and services from your app. Take advantage of user familiarity with their payment
>     methods and a simplified checkout while continuing to use your
>     clearance provider and processes.

Likewise, Apple suggests various options for iOS apps: [free, freemium, subscription, paid, or paymium](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/business-models/).

Comment: This is a good idea, but it's tough to do, since most of these options require the ability to have a good app to piggyback on. And that's hard enough to come up with when you have time to make it and are interacting with people who want the app and can tell you what it needs, what it doesn't, and do alpha and beta testing for you. Even if you hire testers, which the OP sounds like they can't afford, it's still requiring interactions with people.

Answer (score 4):

At least when you are a writer or a programmer you can do it.
Some of the most popular options as of now:

- Writing at [stacker.news](https://stacker.news/recent/freebies) where you can sign up anonymously with a lightning network wallet that supports LNURL-auth or with a nostr pubkey. The payout is in lightning network.
- Writing articles for [Everipedia](https://everipedia.org/). Unlikely to earn more than
  10€ a day unless you write for bounties, which is doable. The payout is in IQ, which you can then trade for the cryptocurrency of the FIAT money of your choice.
- Content creation and blogging on [dtube](https://d.tube/), LBRY, Odyssey, Bitchute, Hive and the like.
- Bounties on [Monero Social](https://bounties.monero.social/). If you know how to code, write technical documentation, or create videos. Payment is in Monero.
- Bounties on [bitcoinbounties.org](https://bitcoinbounties.org/). Payment is in Bitcoin.
- Bounties on [Gitcoin](https://gitcoin.co/). If you know how to code or write technical documentation. Payment is in ETH or ERC-20 tokens, frequently stablecoins.
- Bounties on Github such as for [Haveno](https://github.com/haveno-dex/haveno/blob/master/docs/bounties.md). In case of Haveno the bounties are paid in Monero (good for your privacy). Contributions require creating a
  Github account. Other than doing bounties you can just publish your own software on Github and seek donations via Monero or other cryptocurrencies by publishing you receiving address on the README page of the project. Alternatively, you can seek donations officially, such donations would be in FIAT money, via Github but for this you do need to KYC.
- Freelancing on [Microlancer](https://microlancer.io/) or [Bitsoapbox](https://bitsoapbox.com/). Not so many software projects as on Gitcoin, mostly spam related earning. One of the website's advantages is that they use [lightning network][10], so the onchain fees are not going to be a problem.

As of now, none of the above platforms requires their users to reveal their identities.

Answer (score 3):

With all the restrictions the OP puts on the question, I'm going to say it's nearly impossible to make this work. It could work for someone who is already wealthy and trying to get more wealthy, as in an eccentric wealthy recluse, but what is asked compared to the OP's current position isn't going to happen. The world isn't set up for that kind of thing, and the only reason a wealthy person can do it is because they already have layers artificially in place to do most of the work for them.

Without an ID, most people won't trust you to mop their floors, which goes at least double when it's an online meeting place. There's a reason people generally don't date people they meet online without at least a pic. I don't accept FB or LinkedIn connections with a generic or lack of profile pic.

Most sales platforms still don't pay out in encrypted currency and you can't pay for 99% of anything with it either. You still need some sort of platform (like a bank account) for conversion.

Murtaza Ahmad has the closest thing to what you want with their #1 and #2, but it's a 50% solution at best. And montefiore's answer could work, if you had at least 6 months to work on it, so it's maybe a 10% solution.

Unfortunately for you, Murtaza Ahmad's #3 is the only way to go, and that needs to include having a photo ID, professional human interaction skills, and the willingness to get out of your comfort zone.

If you have time and money, you could set up or write an encrypted currency transaction processor to help with the massive amount of transactions that are backed up in the current system. The fees you and others pay for transactions would go to you. This takes time to write and debug, as well as get people to use. And it takes money to host on a reliable and secure platform. If I had any interest in encrypted currency, I'd be doing this.

Or, if you still had time and money, you could write a system to take payments from any platform (whether it's Apple, YouTube, Etsy, PayPal, banks, or whatever) and instantly transfer it to encrypted currency like you want. People and businesses pay you in dollars, pounds, rubles, yen, or whatever and all you see is BTC in your wallet. Then, when you pay others (such as your landlord, mortgage lender, car repair, groceries, gas, bus fare, and whatever) and it automatically and instantly translates your BTC back to dollars, pounds, rubles, yen, or whatever. People like you would pay for this kind of system. Even if it exists, it's not mainstream enough for most people to know about it, so you can get on the "ground floor" of this industry, eventually making millions or billions.

But you need time, money, and even human interaction to make either of my suggestions work. Even if you do online advertising, you still need money for that, and you need to know when and why it's not working, so you need human interaction. And even if you spend the money for someone else to do it for you, you still need human interaction for them to know what you want out of the ad campaign.

I got into computers so that I could avoid people. I was hoping to get a job fixing computers in some back room somewhere. That didn't happen. I had to be a service rep, talking to people about what's wrong with the computer. This was true  working for small and large businesses as internal IT, as well as when I worked fixing people's personal computers. It still doesn't work as a software dev. I need to work with other devs, managers, Agile product owners, sometimes CxO's, and sometimes outside customers. Since you aren't rich, you can't do all of that through a butler or an associate/representative/secretary.

I'm sorry, but that's the reality of things right now. You haven't found a solution because there isn't one to find at your current level. I'm (finally) making more than decent money right now and it's not possible at my level either. You can make it possible for others to do it, by creating the system from scratch like I outlined above, but that's not going to help you. Simply put, by the time people start accepting your system, you likely won't need it anymore.

Answer (score 1):

In usual freelancing scenarios, you have to interact with people and validate your identification (in case of online marketplaces like Upwork). Considering the constraints you have listed, the best bet to earn online is to do your thing where external contact will remain at minimum.

As you have mentioned programming skills, I would suggest building websites and monetize them using services like Adsense, Amazon Affiliate program etc. You can either write or acquire content, get it optimized for search engines, generate traffic and monetize it accordingly. People are making full time salaries doing this stuff.

Answer (score 0):

It's good that you're thinking about this question, but it's a complex one, and it will be difficult for other people to give a definitive answer. Most people will write about what is popular now (e-commerce, digital marketing, agencies, etc.), but I will say from my experience that after trying all these areas, I realised that I am not interested in any of them. I'm an introverted person and I'm more comfortable working online, so now I earn extra money by selling my images and illustrations that I create myself using web design. Yes, it's not a career or a profession, but it's a hobby that brings in money and I enjoy doing it. Looking back at myself a year ago, I see progress and I'm not afraid of the future. Just know that you are not alone and your basic skills are very good enough to move on) Programming skills are extremely valuable, so it's worth trying your hand at freelancing, there are plenty of offers of varying complexity and pay on the Fiverr and Upwork platforms.

Answer (score -1):

This is impossible.

If you don't mind interacting with people under pseudonym or fake name look for developer communities to join and start networking from there.
Being able to find clients and deliver what client need is "secret trick".

Comment: I start working in freelance being anonymous and without the skills, English and portfolio that said @Jamey in his Question. it's hard, that method not build trust on clients but is not impossible.